# Getting Problem In Adding View Dynamically In Android in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

Hello Guys I was trying to make an app. I have a RelativeLayout which contains a Recycler View. I tried to add the Recycler view dynamically in android. But I am getting a problem with my app. When I try to add Recycler view dynamically In Android then it overlapping another recycler view shown in the image below.

I want to add Recycler View under Recycler View in my Relative Layout.

Here is the image when I run my code

This is the image before clicking the button
-- [image]

This is the image after clicking the button

[image]

You can see the when clicking the button the recycler view was not adding properly I want to add the recycler view properly below the previous recycler view

Here is my code:=

```
int count = 1;
parentLayout  = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_recyclerview);

recyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.layout_container_recyclerview_special_hours);

        button = findViewById(R.id.click_me_tet);


        recyclerView2.setId(1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(SpecialHoursActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SpecialHoursActivity.this));
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, count);
                recyclerView.setLayoutParams(lparams);

                parentLayout.addView(recyclerView);
                count++;
                recyclerView.setId(count);


            }
        });
```

Here is my layout file:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/layout_container_recyclerview_special_hours"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/click_me_tet"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_container_recyclerview_special_hours"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Click Me" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't think there is a requirement of modal and adapter because it was attached to recycler view and the recycler view is working fine.

conclusion:-

I am getting a problem in adding view dynamically to my app in Relative Layout. But My code is not working fine. So if anyone has an answer to this question please reply me

I want to add recycler view below recycler view after clicking the button.

Comment: just curious to know, why are you not using another recycler view to hold them togather?

Comment: @towhid I try but Recycler View under recycler view cause error so i try this can you please help in this

Comment: OK, if you don't want to use recyclerView than you can use listView. that would be much more easy approach.

Comment: @towhid ok thanks but solving this bug will help me to know more and also help other developers too